# Trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is the code that I use to create a table, a sequence and a trigger

```
DROP TABLE CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus;

-- 
-- TABLE: CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus 
--

CREATE TABLE CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus(
    Id             NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
    ShortName      NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
    Description    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ExtDL_JobStatus PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
;



Declare NumOfSequences NUMBER :=0;
Begin
  Select COUNT(*)
  INTO NumOfSequences
  FROM All_Sequences
  WHERE 1=1
    And upper (Sequence_Owner) = upper ('CDR')
    And upper (Sequence_Name) = upper ('ExtDL_JobStatus_Seq');
  If NumOfSequences > 0 Then
    Execute IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus_Seq';
  End If;
End;
/
CREATE SEQUENCE CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus_Seq
    INCREMENT BY 1
    START WITH 1
    NOMAXVALUE 
    NOMINVALUE 
;
/

Declare NumOfTriggers NUMBER :=0;
Begin
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO NumOfTriggers
  FROM All_Triggers
  WHERE 1=1
    And upper (Owner) = upper ('CDR')
    And upper (Trigger_Name) = upper ('ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg');
  If NumOfTriggers > 0 Then
    Execute IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg';
  End If;
End;
/
CREATE TRIGGER CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg
BEFORE INSERT
ON CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (new.Id IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg.nextval into :new.Id from dual;
    END;


/
INSERT INTO ExtDL_JobStatus (Id, ShortName, Description) Values (0, 'Success', 'Fail')
/
SELECT * FROM ExtDL_JobStatus
```

When I execute the code, I get the following output

```
DROP TABLE CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus succeeded.
CREATE TABLE succeeded.
anonymous block completed
CREATE SEQUENCE succeeded.
anonymous block completed
Warning: execution completed with warning
TRIGGER CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg Compiled.

Error starting at line 62 in command:
INSERT INTO ExtDL_JobStatus (Id, ShortName, Description) Values (0, 'Success', 'Fail')
Error at Command Line:62 Column:12
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'CDR.EXTDL_JOBSTATUS_SEQTRG' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
ID                     SHORTNAME              DESCRIPTION            
---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- 

0 rows selected
```

What makes my trigger invalid?

Comment: I have encounter a similar problem once. My problem was cause by having more than one trigger with the same name differing only on the casing. I would check that it wasn't the same problem you have.

Comment: @Falle1234 I checked on that `select * from all_triggers`; no duplicates.

Comment: please let us know what the actual error is: `show error CDR.EXTDL_JOBSTATUS_SEQTRG`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Warning: execution completed with
>   warning TRIGGER
>   CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg Compiled.

This is where your trigger compilation failed.

```
sql> CREATE TRIGGER ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg
  2  BEFORE INSERT
  3  ON ExtDL_JobStatus
  4      FOR EACH ROW
  5      WHEN (new.Id IS NULL)
  6      BEGIN
  7          SELECT ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg.nextval into :new.Id from dual;
  8      END;
  9  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

sql> show errors;
Errors for TRIGGER EXTDL_JOBSTATUS_SEQTRG:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/9      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/16     PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

The problem is because you are using **ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg** in your code and the sequence you created is **ExtDL_JobStatus_Seq**.

Also, if you are trying to run a script like this for creating (compiling) the objects, I would suggest you add the following clause after each trigger/procedure/function creatin statement.

```
SHOW ERRORS;
```

If your statement succceds, that will just produce no errors. If there are any erros, you'll have a detailed description of the errors instead of having to execute the script again.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple typo: your sequence is called `ExtDL_JobStatus_Seq` but in your trigger you reference  `ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg.nextval`.

For future reference it is a good idea to include a call to show error in scripts after each call which compiles PL/SQL (triggers, procedures, etc).  Like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON CDR.ExtDL_JobStatus 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN (new.Id IS NULL) 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT ExtDL_JobStatus_SeqTrg.nextval into :new.Id from dual; 
    END; 
/ 

show errors
```

Incidentally, there's the same typo in the anonymous block which attempst to drop the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to everything previously mentioned, there are two additional typos/errors:

1. The anonymous PL/SQL block that tries to drop the trigger actually says `DROP SEQUENCE`.
2. The insert statement attempts to insert characters strings into the ShortName and Description columns, which are both defined as NUMBER(38, 0).

Comment: I noticed the thing about the datatypes. Somehow everything had changed to one domain - I changed it back to each individual domain